# How to make a Flask application in venv works with Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, jinja2

I'm trying to start a flask application, with flask run, (which was working fine before I installed Anaconda), and I'm getting the following stack trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rodrigo\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\Rodrigo\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Rodrigo\Documents\Project1\frontEnd\venv\Scripts\flask.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Rodrigo\Documents\Project1\frontEnd\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from jinja2 import Markup, escape
  File "C:\Users\Rodrigo\Documents\Project1\frontEnd\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
    _patch_async()
  File "C:\Users\Rodrigo\Documents\Project1\frontEnd\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\__init__.py", line 78, in _patch_async
    from jinja2.asyncsupport import patch_all
  File "C:\Users\Rodrigo\Documents\Project1\frontEnd\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\asyncsupport.py", line 13, in <module>
    import asyncio
  File "C:\Users\Rodrigo\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .base_events import *
  File "C:\Users\Rodrigo\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 39, in <module>
    from . import events
  File "C:\Users\Rodrigo\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 14, in <module>
    import contextvars
  File "C:\Users\Rodrigo\Anaconda3\lib\contextvars.py", line 1, in <module>
    from _contextvars import Context, ContextVar, Token, copy_context

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_contextvars'
```

The Python  version at the system level is 3.7.3
The Python version at venv level is 3.7.0

I've already tried to install contextvars, but it only upgraded an older version and did not fix the problem. In both system level and venv level contextvars requisite is already satisfied.

I'm running this on  Windows 10.

Any idea on what can be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue when using python 3.7.2 on Windows 7.

This is a known bug and should be resolved.
https://bugs.python.org/issue34691

Updating to python 3.7.3 resolved the issue (for me).

Try to update your venv level to  3.7.3